# How to skip inner Rails realisation when debugging with Pry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, pry

When we are debugging behaviour between different classes, sometimes Pry diving into inner Rails classes (like `action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb`, `active_support/callbacks.rb`) or realisation of other plugins (for example New Relic).

What is the best way to skip this code and to debug only through your application code?

PS: help me please to make a proper title for this question if this one is not clear enough.

Comment: I remember when I had my first Rails realisation.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot sorry, I did not catch your thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're stepping through code using `pry-byebug` or `debugger` since `pry` by itself doesn't offer stepping.

You can use `step` which goes line by line and "steps into" method calls (which it seems like you might be doing). Or you can use `next` which "steps over" method calls so that you don't go in too deep.

But you can't avoid going into the framework and your gems, if they are in the execution path, you'll eventually get there. Use `next` to step over method calls you don't want to go into.

Comment: I'm using pry-nav.
Yes, I'm using "next", but I still going into endless lines of code.

Comment: Welcome to framework debugging. If your code is modular enough to run in isolation, that would ease your debugging efforts.